# Application.Idle in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web

I used to work with the desktop application, but sadly my graduation project is a web-base application, how can I make this statement with asp.net

```
Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The concept of Application.Idle doesn't really translate to a web-based application, so please *edit your question* to include an explanation of what your actual requirement is.

Comment: gradation or graduation project?